# Why select of count fetches a lot of rows?

Tags: sql, indexing

Table teams contains 1169 rows, 1133 from them have UserId field !=0. There is an index on the "UserId" field

Query:

`EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM teams WHERE UserId != 0`

returns output that has Estimate of rows to be examined equal to 1133.

Why query need to examine all rows? Should not it just use index for this purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried SELECT COUNT (UserID) ?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the count of index entries? Remember for a clustered index, the table IS the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will examine almost all rows because you want almost all rows (because you said UserId != 0). Sure, you then make a "count" so you show only one record, but they all had to be fetched in order to count them.
If you where to do

```
select count(1) from teams where UserId = 100
```

then it will examine ony a few rows, because you are asking for a precise value (UserId = XX as opposed to UserId  != yy).

Comment: But why use used COUNT(1)? How is that different from COUNT(*)?

Comment: @Budda On earlier times using * would fetch the whole row structure and then count them, so using count(any constant) would avoid that. This probably is not the case on current DBMS, but I got the habit. In any case, the importat thing in my response is the "UserId = xx" as opposed to "UserId != xx". I'll edit the response to clarify.

Comment: @AlejoBrz: I don't know of any DBMS where `count(*)` and `count(1)` has ever made a difference. That was always only a myth.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Probably, but it does make sense! :-)